# How big is "duas partes decimarum"?

Tags: medieval-latin, numbers

This record is from *[The Cartulary of Newnham Priory](https://www.bedfordshirehrs.org.uk/content/publication/cartulary-newnham-priory)*, transcribing a record from 1166. Simon [II] de Beauchamp granted whole churches and fractions of other tithes to Newnham priory. Here is how it was written:

> Concessi eciam eis has decimas, scilicet duas partes decimarum in
> molendinis et pannagiis et in ceteris dominiorum de Stotfolde, de
> Hagenes, de Kaishoo, de Lincelade, de Euersholt, de Hunesdone, de
> Puttenho, de Calworth', de Asple, de toto feodo meo in Holewelle.

This must have been a precisely-understood account, because it's a valuable gift. Elsewhere the priory records gifts down to the farthing. But various modern interpretations of this text online and in print quote differing fractions for the gift. Here's a straight google translation:

> I have also granted to them these tithes, namely, two parts of tithes
> in mills and pannages and in the other lordships of Stotfold, of
> Hages, of Kaishoo, of Lincelade, of Euersholt, of Hunesdon, of
> Puttenho, of Calworth, of Asple, for all my fee in Holwelle.

But google also translates `scilicet duas partes decimarum in molendinis et pannagiis` as `namely two-thirds of the tithes in mills and pannages`. And also translates `duas partes decimarum` as `two-tenths`.

My understanding is that the tithe in mills and pannage should be one tenth of the total produce. So two thirds of that would be 6.67% of the total produce. Or two tenths would be 2% of the total produce. This must be a precise definition, but **just what is the number**, please?

Comment: "Concessieciam" -- this should perhaps be "Concessi etiam"?

Comment: Apologies, that was my mistake. The published text reads "Concessi eciam". I edited the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Allen & Greenough [135e](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/category-search?field_gl_section_number_value=135) explains,

> When the denominator is one greater than the numerator, only the
> numerator is given.
>
> duae partēs two-thirds
>
> trēs partēs three-fourths, etc.

So, *duas partes* means two-thirds.

Comment: Thank you very much, that sems to be completely clear.

Answer (score 4):

A bit modified because the verb was weird:

> Concessi etiam eis has decimas, scilicet duas partes decimarum in molendinis et pannagiis et in ceteris dominiorum de Stotfolde [...]

Translation:

> And I granted to them these tithes, namely two parts of tithes as mill-houses and as privileges of feeding swine in the woods and as others of ownership of Stotfolde ...

It seems that the formula *duas partes decimarum* means "two-thirds of the tithes". See, for example, Eyton (1860) p. 271.

Eyton, R. W. (1860) Antiquities of Shropshire, Vol. 11. London: J.R. Smith. https://books.google.fi/books?id=t01NAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA271

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo. Corrected in the question. I have a habit of making life harder than it needs to be... Thanks for your help!